# Performance of Spark structured streaming Stream-Stream join

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying out the stream-stream join feature of spark Structured streaming using Spark 2.4.0.

I am just joining two simple set of data just to observe the performance of stream-stream join. I am currently running this in my local machine with just a few input records. I observe that it takes more than a couple of minutes to join data from two streams and write output to Kafka.

Here is what I have been trying :

```
val in1Df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", s"$kafkaHost:$kafkaPort")
  .option("subscribe", config.getString("SparkStrucStreamingPoc.inTopic1"))
  .load()
  .select($"timestamp" as "timestamp1",$"value" cast "string" as "value1")

val in2Df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", s"$kafkaHost:$kafkaPort")
  .option("subscribe", config.getString("SparkStrucStreamingPoc.inTopic2"))
  .load()
  .select($"timestamp"  as "timestamp2", $"value" cast "string" as "value2")

val in1DfWithWatermark = in1Df
  .select($"timestamp1",$"value1")
  .withWatermark("timestamp1", "10 seconds")

val in2DfWithWatermark = in2Df
  .select($"timestamp2",$"value2")
  .withWatermark("timestamp2", "20 seconds")

val joinedDf = in1DfWithWatermark.join(in2DfWithWatermark,
  expr(("""value1 = value2 AND
                 timestamp2 >= timestamp1 AND
                 timestamp2 <= timestamp1 + interval 1 minutes""")))

joinedDf.select(($"value1").alias("value"))
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("topic", config.getString("SparkStrucStreamingPoc.outTopic"))
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", s"$kafkaHost:$kafkaPort")
  .option("checkpointLocation", config.getString("SparkStrucStreamingPoc.checkpoint"))
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Has anyone else observed this kind of a behavior ? Does it usually take this long to join two streams ?

Comment: Is the Kafka cluster or instance and your Spark Job running on the same machine ? If yes do you maybe have other processes running that may interfere ?

Comment: Can you maybe show a sample set of your data

Comment: I am running the spark code in my local machine. I have the kafka cluster running as docker containers in my machine. The input records that I used are just simple words or numbers like: TEST, 10, etc.,